# How to install data_files of python package into home directory

Tags: python, pip, twine

Here's my setup.py

```
setup(
    name='shipane_sdk',

    version='1.0.0.a5',

    # ...

    data_files=[(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.shipane_sdk', 'config'), ['config/scheduler-example.ini'])],

    # ...
)
```

Packing & Uploading commands:

```
python setup.py sdist
python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
twine upload dist/*
```

Installing command:

```
pip install shipane_sdk
```

But, it doesn't install the **config/scheduler-example.ini** under **~/.shipane_sdk**

The pip documents says:

> setuptools allows absolute “data_files” paths, and pip honors them as
>   absolute, when installing from sdist. This is not true when installing
>   from wheel distributions. Wheels don’t support absolute paths, and
>   they end up being installed relative to “site-packages”. For
>   discussion see wheel Issue #92.

Do you know how to do **installing from sdist**?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to this problem and it is all very confusing how inconsistent the packaging tools work. Some time ago I found the following workaround worked for me best with sdist (note that it doesn't work with wheels!):

1. Instead of using data_files, attach the files to your package using MANIFEST.in, which in your case could look like this:

   ```
   include config/scheduler-example.ini
   ```
2. Copy the files "manually" to chosen location using this snippet in setup.py:

   ```
   if 'install' in sys.argv:
       from pkg_resources import Requirement, resource_filename
       import os
       import shutil

       # retrieve the temporary path where the package has been extracted to for installation
       conf_path_temp = resource_filename(Requirement.parse(APP_NAME), "conf")

       # if the config directory tree doesn't exist, create it
       if not os.path.exists(CONFIG_PATH):
           os.makedirs(CONFIG_PATH)

       # copy every file from given location to the specified ``CONFIG_PATH``
       for file_name in os.listdir(conf_path_temp):
           file_path_full = os.path.join(conf_path_temp, file_name)
           if os.path.isfile(file_path_full):
               shutil.copy(file_path_full, CONFIG_PATH)
   ```

In my case "conf" was the subdirectory in the package that contained my data files and they were supposed to be installed into CONFIG_PATH which was something like /etc/APP_NAME

Comment: Thanks. That was already resolved by using --no-binary switch. I will add a alternative answer later.